# Loading properties in java program

Tags: java, properties

I'm a begginner java programmer; now I'm using J2SE and NetBeans 6.9.1 to code an application.

The issue I'm facing now is to load properties from a well known location in my local filesystem using a singleton class. What annoys me is that I get an error which is claiming for a throws clause or catch the exception where the INSTANCE variable is being initialized. May anyone help me undestand this.

Thanks in advance.

The code is as follows :

```
package cat.oai.atapplications.phot;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 *
 * @author fdalmau
 */
public class PhotPropertiesManager {

    private static Properties photProperties;

    private PhotPropertiesManager() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        photProperties = LoadProperties();
    }

    public static PhotPropertiesManager getInstance() {
        return PhotPropertiesManagerHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public static Properties getPhotProperties() {
        return PhotPropertiesManager.photProperties;
    }

    private static Properties LoadProperties() throws FileNotFoundException,
                                                      IOException {

        Properties defaultPhotProperties = new Properties();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("defaultphot");
        defaultPhotProperties.load(in);
        in.close();

        Properties applicationPhotProperties = 
                                     new Properties(defaultPhotProperties);

        in = new FileInputStream("lastexecutionphot");
        applicationPhotProperties.load(in);
        in.close();

        return applicationPhotProperties;
    }

    private static class PhotPropertiesManagerHolder {

        /******
          The problem is is this line of code:
         ******/
        static final PhotPropertiesManager INSTANCE = new PhotPropertiesManager();

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give us the error? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: It's most likely asking for the try catch because when you declare PhotPropertiesManager() you have it throwing multiple exceptions.

Comment: @Max you nailed it, Francesc, you need to use a "try...catch" block, resource http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: Java isn't C# method names should be `lowerCamelCase` to visually differentiate from Class names which should be in `UpperCamelCase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a static field cannot throw a check exception.  I would simplify the code like this.

```
public enum PhotPropertiesManager {;
    private static final Properties PHOT_PROPERTIES = new Properties();

    static {
        try {
            load("defaultphot");
            load("lastexecutionphot");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void load(String filename) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        PHOT_PROPERTIES.load(in);
        in.close();
    }

    public static Properties getPhotProperties() {
        return PHOT_PROPERTIES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both responses had been very useful for me. Nevertheless I'll choose the one posted by Peter Lawrey because I find it nicer and more compact

Comment: `nicer and more compact` is a personal quest of mine. ;) You can tick the answer you like on the left to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a try-catch block in order to use your code because you're throwing exceptions when you declare:

```
PhotPropertiesManager()
```

Java makes you basically try to ensure that your program won't crash (at least outright) by having you "catch" the errors your program might encounter and then deal with those errors accordingly.

Your try-catch should look something like:

```
try{
PhotPropertiesManager();
}
catch(Exception e){
whateveryouwanttodo();
}
```

More documentation courtesy of Dorin, [[try-catch]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)